# Long press event for Button is not working

Tags: android, android-button

I want to use simple `OnLongClickListener` in my `ImageButton`. If I hold button pressed for longer time, it should repeat function inside as long as I'm holding it pressed.

I did it like this:

```
button.setOnLongClickListener {
       actionOnButtonClick()
       false
}
```

But it is not working if I'm holding button. `actionOnButtonClick()` is called only once as I pushed button.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can set `OnTouchListener` and check when button is pressed and keep checking until the button released:

```kotlin
private val handler = Handler()
private lateinit var runnable: Runnable

private val longClickDelay = 2000L //milliseconds
private val updateDelay = 500L //milliseconds

//...

var isPressed = false
button.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        isPressed = true
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, longClickDelay)
    } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        isPressed = false
    v.performClick()
}

runnable = Runnable {
    if (isPressed) {

        //call your function here

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, updateDelay)
    }
}
```

the function invokes 2 seconds after pressed (`longClickDelay`) and updates every 500 milliseconds (`updateDelay`).

Comment: This is working if I press a button for longer time. But this eliminates single tap (on click functionality). If I have Button I have to press it for 2 seconds to get it work. If I just lightly tap on it, time between MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN(PRESS) and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP(RELEASE) is too short to execute code in Runnable. I tried to implement GestureDetector to listen to SingleTap event but it is not working. I even used only 100ms delay for Runnable but still no changes

Answer (score 0):

Return `true` instead of returning `false` to consume the event.

You long click the button, if it returns true then it does the work. If it returns false then it does its work and also calls the short click and then the onClick also works.

Comment: Do you have any `onClickListener()` linked to the button? In fact, you don't necessary need an `ImageButton`, just an `ImageView` can do the trick